# Can signal processing be applied successfully to price data from financial markets?

Tags: analytic-signal

Price/volume data from financial markets are like signals. Can these information be applied to signal processing to generate profits successfully?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not sure that this is a great forum for this sort of question, though. [Quantitative Finance](http://quant.stackexchange.com) would be the first place that comes to mind, but I doubt a basic question like this would be accepted over there based on its typical depth of subject matter. The likely answer to your question: yes, but good luck finding someone to tell you how.

Answer (score 6):

Well of course you can apply it and many people try. If anyone has been really successful in doing this they probably are sitting now on a nice warm beach sipping Martinis, so this information may not be easy to come by.

Answer (score 5):

The financial market data normally available does not comply with the Nyquist sampling criteria.  Any information potentially in the data samples available to high frequency traders has to be taken advantage of before it is reflected in the prices, which leads to some profits in making exotic FPGA-based custom signal processing hardware.  According to theories of Talib and Mandlebrot, all the entities attempting to rapidly act on any of this information processing contributes to the non-Gaussian/"fat-tailed"/chaotic behavior, which may or may not be good for market stability in the opinion of some. Signal processing algorithms that assume the underlying model might be a stationary composite of Gaussian and linear low order differential equations are likely unsuitable for extracting usable information from data with the above behaviors.